# Converting Excel to Google Sheets, issue with cell colors and gridlines

Tags: python, excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a problem with how cell colors are treated in Excel and Google Sheets. I noticed that in Excel when you color a bunch of cells, the default gridlines become invisible. However, in Google Sheets the gridlines stay semi-transparent.

Because of that, when I import an Excel file into Google Sheets, the colored cells don't switch from one style to another. The gridlines remain invisible. What's even weirder is that when you try reseting the color in Google Sheets, you don't get those semi-transparent gridlines back.

If what I described above isn't clear, check out this image: [image: The issue 1]

I honestly doubt that anyone here knows why this is happening or how to fix it. But I'm asking such a question here because...

Currently I have a python program that generates excel files and the files that I'm generating currently happen to have A LOT of colored cells.

What else could I do to avoid this issue? Is there a way to somehow copy paste my python code into Google Sheets? Would I have to use a different language to make it work? What can I do in general?

Comment: I'll be throwing ideas here since this is sort of a general question, so you can start with using [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create) instead since they also have python samples for it.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I was thinking about using the Google Sheets Apps Script which is done in js, but because it's done in js I started learning it. I think I'll do what you're suggesting for now and learn more js anyway since it might come in handy in the future.